# Unir Fecha y Hora con SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datetime

Hola estoy trabajando con SQL 14, y deseo unir dos columnas una es Fecha y la Otra Hora, he intentado varias formas pero ninguna me lo respecta, me refiero a que se fucionan o unen las columnas pero cuando hago una consulta no se ve reflejado el cambio.

```
SELECT Planta, Fecha FROM (
SELECT Planta, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), Fecha) +' '+ CONVERT(varchar(11), 
Hora) AS datetime) AS Fecha

FROM dbo.tblHideUtilizationJDE
WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '2017-07-23 06:00:00.000' AND '2017-07-26 05:59:59.000'
GROUP BY Planta,  Fecha
```

Comment: Que tipo de datos son Fecha y Hora?

Comment: ¿Cómo se están guardando los datos en las columnas `Fecha` y `Hora` de tu tabla `tblHideUtilizationJDE`?. Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/96170/edit) y agregar más detalle.

Comment: Estoy en un lío similar pero no me funciona.
Tengo tres columnas tipo fechas de tres tablas distintas... CONVERT(DATETIME, Tbl_FacturaCompra.FechaCompra) + CONVERT(DATETIME, Tbl_FacturaVenta.FechaVenta) + CONVERT(DATETIME, Tbl_OtraOperacion.FechaOO) AS FECHITA pero no me funciona. La idea es que en una columna de esta SELECT de tres tablas rescate las fechas de las tres columnas para un informe. Alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Intenta de la siguiente manera: SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), Tbl_FacturaCompra.FechaCompra) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), Tbl_FacturaVenta.FechaVenta) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR (30), Tbl_OtraOperacion.FechaOO) AS FECHITA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es sencillo, utiliza la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT Planta, Fecha = CONVERT(DATETIME, Fecha) + CONVERT(DATETIME, Hora)
  FROM dbo.tblHideUtilizationJDE
 WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '2017-07-23 06:00:00.000' AND '2017-07-26 05:59:59.000'
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCombinedDateTime(@FechaEntrada datetime, @Hora as int) returns datetime
as
begin
DECLARE @FECHA NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @FechaUnida DATETIME

DECLARE @HoraTxt nvarchar(10)

IF @HORA>23 or @Hora<0
    SET @HoraTxt='23:59:59'
ELSE
    SET @HoraTxt = right('0'+ltrim(str(@hora)),2) + ':00'
SET @FECHA = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @FechaEntrada, 105) + ' ' + @horatxt

SET @FechaUnida =  @Fecha--  convert(datetime,@FECHA,113)

return @FechaUnida
end
```